# CMake add -ldl at end of link stage of add_library

Tags: c, ubuntu, cmake, shared-libraries

I wrote/maintain a small unit test library on github https://github.com/acgreek/ExtremeCUnit built using cmake. You can checkout and run some  tests via 'cmake test' after checking out. It was working great on Cygwin and Ubuntu (my only home systems). I recent upgrade to ubuntu 13.10 and the library stopped linking with the test binary because the ExtremeUnitC library now needs to be linked with -ldl at the link stage (via add_library) and additionally the -ldl needs to be add to the end of the link line (some change to gcc it seems). In prior version of Ubuntu, the add_library target didn't need the -ldl  until the test object  was linked with the ExtremeUnitC library

Basically what I need is for the results of make VERBOSE=10, when it get to the following stage

```
Linking C shared library libExtremeCUnit.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/link.txt --verbose=10
/usr/bin/gcc  -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3 -fPIC  -ldl   -shared -Wl,-    soname,libExtremeCUnit.so -o libExtremeCUnit.so CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/main.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/runner.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/util.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/findtest_names.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/assert_support.c.o
```

I need it to be,

```
Linking C shared library libExtremeCUnit.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/link.txt --verbose=10
/usr/bin/gcc  -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3 -fPIC  -ldl   -shared -Wl,-    soname,libExtremeCUnit.so -o libExtremeCUnit.so CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/main.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/runner.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/util.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/findtest_names.c.o CMakeFiles/ExtremeCUnit.dir/assert_support.c.o -ldl
```

how should I edit my CMakeList.txt to that in a clean/portable way?

You can also send me a pull request so you can get the credit of fixing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just needed to add

```
target_link_libraries(ExtremeCUnit dl)
```

Comment: You can also use `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}`

Comment: @mchiasson What's `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}`?

Comment: @John https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DL_LIBS.html

Answer (score 7):

```
if(CMAKE_DL_LIBS)
    target_link_libraries(ExtremeCUnit ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
endif()
```

Comment: Does it potable on windows?

Comment: @John that's precisely why I am guarding it with `if(CMAKE_DL_LIBS)` because the variable doesn't exist for windows/MSVC but should exists if you are using cygwin or mingw. So the answer is yes: my answer works on windows.